# How to let user select a month and then show the max value

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table that has a column named 'month name', which then has a row for every day in that month. Theres also a column for rainfall, which shows the amount of rainfall in each day of the month. How can I get the user to select a month, and then show the maximum and minimum rainfall for that month?

Answer (score 0):

To Find The Max Or Min Value Based On Multiple Criteria:

Enter this formula into a cell you want place the result : `=MAX(IF(A2:A13=F1,IF(B2:B13=F2,C2:C13)))`

In this formula: `A2:A13` is the data which contains the criteria1, `B2:B13` is the data range which contains the criteria2, `F1` and `F2` are the criteria you are based on, `C2:C13` refers to the range you want to return the max value. Then press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` keys simultaneously, the max value where the corresponding value in `A2:A13` equals the value in `F1`, and the corresponding value in `B2:B13` equals the value in `F2` is returned.

To get the min value based on these criteria, please apply this formula: `=MIN(IF(A2:A13=F1,IF(B2:B13=F2,C2:C13)))`, and remember to press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` keys together.

Answer (score 0):

To give a method for the user to select a month you can use data validation.

Either have a list of the 12 months in cells or you can enter them direct in the data validation editing box. Select the list type and you end up with a cell with a drop-down arrow.

On a smartphone so no image possible.